# Unable to identify the host : Fabric

Tags: python, fabric

I m trying to use fabric module through simple python module

**remoteExc.py**

```
from fabric.api import *
def clone_repo(IPADDRESS,USER,fPath,git_url):
  env.hosts_string = IPADDRESS
  env.user = USER
  env.key_filename = fPath
  env.disable_known_hosts = 'True'
  run('git clone %s' % (git_url))
```

**mainFile.py**

```
from remoteExc import clone_repo
clone_repo(ipAddress,user,fPath,git_url)
```

When i execute it says

> python mainfile.py
>
> No hosts found. Please specify (single) host string for connection:

Please enlight me where i make a mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo. `env.host_string = IPADDRESS` - you've got an `env.hosts_string` instead.

Also, generally you run fabric via `fab` - unless you're trying to do something fairly non-standard, be aware that running it via `python` probably isn't what you want to do. See the Fabric docs for a pretty good intro.

http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.7/tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks man it is a typo, my requirement is executing the fabric commands from web interface.

Comment: @naga4ce right so, a word of warning. I have actually used fabric as a library in this way, and ultimately the command-line-oriented nature of it always becomes an issue - the biggest reason being that `env` is global, it's not ever supposed to deal with multiple ongoing tasks, whereas web apps often do (read: multi-threading). Fabric is mighty convenient, tho. I guess I'd recommend having any code that talks to fabric run outside of the web app process, a-la celery, else you're tying yourself to a single-threaded, one-request-per-process deployment setup.

Comment: Thank you so much for such insight. Will keep that in mind while developing.